# Why do we need to consider $ \hat{0} = \hat{m} $ separately in the proof for the union of all residue classes being $ \mathbb{Z} $?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

The book *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* by Apostol states in Theorem 5.10 (c):

> The $ m $ residue classes $ \hat{1}, \hat{2}, \dots, \hat{m} $ are disjoint and their union is the set of all integers.

The proof goes like this:

> Hence by part (b) the residue classes
> $$ \hat{0}, \hat{1}, \hat{2}, \dots, \widehat{m - 1} $$
> are disjoint. But every integer $x$ must be in exactly one of these classes because $ x = qm + r $ where $ 0 \le r < m $, so $ x \equiv r \pmod{m}$ and hence $ x \in \hat{r} $. Since $ \hat{0} = \hat{m} $ this proves (c).

Why is the last sentence necessary for the proof. What if we did not write "Since $ \hat{0} = \hat{m} $ this proves (c)."? Will the proof remain incomplete then and why?

Answer (score 3):

The statement is that the classes $[1], \cdots, [m]$ are disjoint, but the author actually proved that $[0], \cdots [m - 1]$ are disjoint. So to connect these two they observed that $[0] = [m]$ and so the two sets of residue classes are the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Hence by part (b) the residue classes
> $$ \hat{0}, \hat{1}, \hat{2}, \dots, \widehat{m - 1} $$
> are disjoint. But every integer $x$ must be in exactly one of these classes because $ x = qm + r $ where $ 0 \le r < m $, so $ x \equiv r \pmod{m}$ and hence $ x \in \hat{r} $. Since $ \hat{0} = \hat{m} $ this proves (c).

The above analysis (including the unspecified part [b]) demonstrates that

$$ \hat{0}, \hat{1}, \hat{2}, \dots, \widehat{m - 1} $$

are **disjoint and comprehensive** (i.e. that every integer belongs to exactly one of the above equivalence classes).

In order to **then** demonstrate that the equivalence classes

$$ \hat{1}, \hat{2}, \dots, \widehat{m - 1}, \widehat{m}$$

are disjoint and comprehensive you must then make the observation that $\hat{0} = \widehat{m}.$